# Custom Tooltips/Bubbles in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know there's pdMarker(http://www.pixeldevelopment.com/pdmarker.asp) that works wonderfully with Maps API v2 to produce custom tooltips and bubbles. But how about for V3?

Answer (score 1):

Right now pdmarker works perfectly fine for V3, you just need to use V3 methods when working with map:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function (e) {
    ib.open(map, marker);
});
```

Comment: I don't see how this is possible.  The PdMarker source code assumes the presence of GMap2 and other V2 classes that will not be present when using the V3 mapping API.  If you have PdMarker source code that works perfectly find with the V3 API, please share it.